# How to install pyarrow , fastparquet offline?

Tags: python-3.x, pyarrow, fastparquet

I want to install pyarrow, fastparquet offline. I have network issue to download python packages using pip, so trying to download pyarrow from pypi.org/project/pyarrow/#files and install it but i'm getting error C:\Users\Public\pyarrow-0.17.1\setup.py not found, Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: first of all find their source file , you can easily get those files from their git-hub or pypi files section https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/#files and then place it to lib folder or use it directly from working directory

Comment: Thank you. I have download pyarrow source file and moved to \Anaconda3\Lib folder but didn't work. Also, i have tried to install using pip install C:\Users\Public\pyarrow-0.17.1\setup.py, again didn't install. Please advise how to install.